# Banner Rotativo Simples

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Galera, desejo fazer um banner rotativo bem simples, com apenas as setas dos lados e uma imagem que troque toda de uma vez que clicado, mas gostaria de usar o mínimo possível de Jquery ou Javascript, tentei fazer mas estou meio enferrujado no desenvolvimento com Jquery e Javascript e tive muitos problemas com plugins que encontrei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seriam no máximo 5 imagens que se alternam quando clicado o botão para os lados.
Se possível fazer sem Jquery e Javascript. Certa vez fiz algo semelhante apenas com CSS mas não lembro como e não sei se é possível.

Comment: Qual o problema com jQuery ou Javacript? Também estou aprendendo e gostaria de saber se tem algum motivo especial para não usar.

Answer (score 3):

Precisei um slider outro dia, e o melhor e mais facil que achei foi esse:
[FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)

jquery:

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**DEMO:**
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html

Answer (score 3):

É perfeitamente possível fazer isso apenas com HTML e CSS. Basta você colocar cada slide numa DIV com uma âncora, englobá-los todos com uma outra DIV, que será seu container, e criar links dentro de cada slide apontando para os slides anteriores e posteriores.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slide1">
        ....
    <a href="#slide2">Slide 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2">
        <a href="#slide1">Slide 1</a>
        ....
        <a href="#slide3">Slide 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2">
        <a href="#slide2">Slide 2</a>
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Com o CSS você deve estilizar o container em bloco com uma largura e altura que permita a visualização apenas do conteúdo de um slide (incluindo os links) utilizando a propriede overflow:hidden para ocultar os demais.

O problema dessa técnica é que cada clique representa um reload na página, e uma solução com javascript, além de não ser nada do outro mundo, representaria um ganho de trabalho, desempenho e visual muito maior.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o plugin [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Ele cria slides e possui diversas configurações e modos diferentes. Apesar das muitas configurações ele é super fácil e versátil.

Basta incluir o CSS, jQuery e libs do plugin no seu HTML, adicionar a classe ou id no seu código e iniciá-lo com apenas 1 linha.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="your-class">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
    setting-name: setting-value
  });
});
```

Todas as configurações estão disponíveis na documentação dele.

Answer (score 2):

Tenho um exemplo usando apenas HTML e CSS.

HTML:

```
<section class="carousel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <label for="toggle" onclick>pausar</label>
    <div class="paineis">
        <article class="page1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Slide%201" alt=""></article>
        <article class="page2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Slide%202" alt=""></article>
        <article class="page3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Slide%203" alt=""></article>
        <article class="page4"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Slide%204" alt=""></article>
        <article class="page5"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Slide%205" alt=""></article>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes carousel{
    0%    { left:0; }
    11%   { left:0; }
    12.5% { left:-100%; }
    23.5% { left:-100%; }
    25%   { left:-200%; }
    36%   { left:-200%; }
    37.5% { left:-300%; }
    48.5% { left:-300%; }
    50%   { left:-400%; }
    61%   { left:-400%; }
    62.5% { left:-300%; }
    73.5% { left:-300%; }
    75%   { left:-200%; }
    86%   { left:-200%; }
    87.5% { left:-100%; }
    98.5% { left:-100%; }
    100%  { left:0; }
    /* daqui: http://csswizardry.com/2011/10/fully-fluid-responsive-css-carousel/ */
}
@keyframes go{
    0%    {  }
    100%    { left:-300%; }
}
@keyframes back{
    0%    { left:0; }
    100%  { left:100%; }
}
.carousel{
    width:100%; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    height:100%;}
.paineis{
    width:500% /* article w * 5 */; 
    overflow:hidden;  
    height:100%;  
    animation:carousel 30s infinite; position:relative;}
article{
    float:left; 
    width:20%;} 
img{
    height:100%; 
    width:100%}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .paineis{animation-play-state:paused; animation: go 10s}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/mapreuss/pen/ECGrB

Ele não tem as setas de avançar e voltar, mas dá para pausar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) que é de facílima configuração e atende às suas necessidades.